# maintenance mode after error occurs while running update

Tags: maintenance-mode, updating

Error occurs While I'm running update for my drupal site.  And it stuck in maintenance mode.
I can't log in to it using /user/login.

I changed $update_free_access = TRUE in settings.php and run update.php.
And I see this screen.

[image]
It says ctools module is missing.
How can I re-install module when I can't login as administrator?

**[Edit]**
In the hope of getting the module back, I restored the database with my backup sql-dump via phpmyadmin.
After that, it came to 500 internal server error.

I don't know what was wrong?
Is there any way I can restore my site back on?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Most housekeeping tasks like these can be done using Drush, a Drupal command line managing tool. For example, you can reinstall the module using

```
drush pm-disable modulename
drush pm-uninstall modulename
drush pm-enable modulename
```

the database can be updated by issuing

```
drush updatedb
```

And code is easily updated with

```
drush pm-update
```

To use drush you need a shell access to a server your site runs on. No authorization as Drupal user is needed.